# Changing the start menu icon in Xubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, icons

I'm trying to change the appearance of my desktop and I was wondering if there was a way to change the icon for the start menu,in Xubuntu, from a mouse to something else?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Right-click it and select Properties, then click the Icon button and choose the one you want.

[image: Xubuntu screenshot illustrating the process]